Why cant i see all light and shadow properties in Blender version 4.2 and EEVEE renderer
Im new to Blender and im using version 4.2 and while trying to follow a tutorial i cant see the same light/shadow porperties as the video shows.
I should be seeing the properties for Cascaded shadow map and contact shadows, as well as other options but all i get are these, i made sure i am using the EEVEE renderer and not the Benchmark or cycles.

The EEVEE render engine has been reworked completely in 4.2 and many things in older tutorials are not the same like before. See these links: Blender 4.2 LTS release notes: EEVEE and EEVEE migration from older versions to Blender 4.2 LTS

@GordonBrinkmann that appears to be a complete answer, please do post it as such.

@TheLabCat It's just a reference to the Blender pages and all I could answer would just be copy and paste of the text there...

Well, even without the links, there is still an answer there. It’s answers that are entirely links that are problematic, I think.
